# NextGen Gallery - automatically create gallery sub page?

Tags: plugins, gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery, support

In order to use Breadcrumbs NavXT to display the title of a gallery, you need to create a new gallery subpage that the gallery will link to.

Is there a way to make NextGen automatically create this gallery subpage named by the title of the gallery?

Comment: Can you please review your question? Could you find an answer so far? If not, probably you want to place a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

In gallery settings there is an checkbox option called "Deactivate gallery page link:" 
When that is checked "The album will not link to a gallery subpage. The gallery is shown on the same page. "  You may have already done it but if not uncheck it if its checked and see what happens.

David